# Do any online payment providers allow payment to alipay accounts or Chinese bank accounts from outside of China?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment, credit-card, alipay

Sorry if I'm asking in the wrong place... Do any online payment providers allow payment from outside of China (My company is in New Zealand) to either Alipay or Chinese bank accounts?

We are a language platform and are looking to take payment from clients generally in Western countries and transfer them to interpreters bank accounts or Alipay accounts as they are generally from China.

I've tried looking into PayPal, Stripe, Braintree. PayPal can only pay to another PayPal account and Stripe and Braintree are not yet active in China.

I would much rather Westerners could pay using their PayPal account and we could transfer it directly to an interpreters Alipay account but I haven't seen how this might be possible yet.

Answer (score 1):

Providers supporting Alipay include:

1) Stripe
2) PaymentWall
3) Adyen
4) checkout.com

and more

At least PaymentWall also supports UnionPay.